# 1С Битрикс API. Получить все свойства товара

Tags: api, битрикс

Требуется вывести массив всех активных товаров с их свойствами.
В документации был предложен следующий способ:
`$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID","PROPERTY_*");`
Т.е. выбрать все свойства, но это не работает.
Когда выбираю одно свойтсво: `Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID","PROPERTY_COLOR")`, то оно работает как надо.
Так же пробовал через `$props = $item->GetProperties()`, но возвращается лишь пустой массив.

Есть ли ещё способы вывести **все** характеристики товара?

Answer (score 1):

Что-то покрутил, честно признаюсь, не понял, где ошибся. В итоге всё заработало. Ниже привожу рабочий код:

```
<?php
//Типы цен, которые должны быть в массиве
$base_price = 4;
$opt_price = 14;
//Выбираю все активные товары и некоторые поля
$db_res = CIBlockElement::GetList(
    array(),
    array('IBLOCK_TYPE'=>'catalog','IBLOCK_ID' => 2, 'ACTIVE' => 'Y'),
    false,
    false,
    array('ID','IBLOCK_ID','NAME','IBLOCK_SECTION_ID','DETAIL_PICTURE','DETAIL_TEXT')
);

while(($ar_res = $db_res->GetNextElement())){
    //Получаю поля товара 
    $ar_fields = $ar_res->GetFields();
    //Получаю все (активные и не пустые) свойства товара 
    $ar_props = $ar_res->GetProperties(Array(),Array('ACTIVE'=>'Y','EMPTY'=>'N'));
    //Получаю цены товара
    $prices = CPrice::GetList(
        array(),
        array(
            "PRODUCT_ID" => $ar_fields['ID'],
            "CATALOG_GROUP_ID" => Array($base_price,$opt_price)
        )
    );
    //Добавляю цены в массив
    while ($price = $prices->Fetch()) {
        $ar_fields['PRICES'][$price['CATALOG_GROUP_ID']] = $price;
    }
    //Добавляю свойства в массив
    $ar_fields['PROPERTIES'] = $ar_props;

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($ar_fields); echo "</pre>";

}
```

Надеюсь, это кому-то поможет.